# File upload to Amazon S3 via Cloudfront using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

How to upload file using AngularJS to Amazon S3 via CLoudfront service.

Comment: I did not use any of those services, but probably via POST request? :) Try `$http.post('aws_url', your_file_encoded_to_base64` . $http is built in http service in angular

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Cloudfront is a CDN and you can't use it to upload files to S3. A simple google search will reveal a lot of ways to upload files to S3 using angular.